# Efficient way of checking if record exists in database within a loop?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm looping over a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
{"code:" "ST", "date": "2021-06-30", "open": 500, "close": 510, "volume": 2000}
```

And I got a table in my DB where `code` is a foreign key to another table:

```
class HistoricStockData(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField()
    open_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    close_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    volume = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "historic_stockdata"
        verbose_name_plural = "Historic Stock Data"
```

I am then trying to insert these HistoricStockData instances to the db

```
stocks = []
for value in data: # data is the big json file that I'm parsing
    stock_name = value["code"]
    date = value["date"]
    open_price = value["open"]
    close_price = value["close"]
    volume = value["volume"]

    
    stock_info = {
        "stock": Stock.objects.get(stock=stock_name), # only append if I get a match here 
        "date": date,
        "open_value": open_price,
        "close_value": close_price,
        "volume": volume
    }
    stocks.append(stock_info)
```

My question is, how can I only append each individual `stock_info` to `stocks` if I get a match on

```
Stock.objects.get(stock=stock_name)
```

Doing a try/catch block with a Stock.DoesNotExist clause seems to be very inefficient if the list is big - resulting in a lot of db queries

Is this the best way?

```
try: 
    stock_info = {
        "stock": Stock.objects.get(stock=stock_name),
        "date": date,
        "open_value": open_price,
        "close_value": close_price,
        "volume": volume
    }
except Stock.DoesNotExist:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one query to fetch all the needed `Stock` instances and put them in a dictionary. With this you can then make lookups very easily to check if a stock is present:

```
stock_names = [value['code'] for value in data]
stock_map = {stock.stock: stock for stock in Stock.objects.filter(stock__in=stock_names)}

stocks = []
for value in data:
    stock_name = value["code"]
    date = value["date"]
    open_price = value["open"]
    close_price = value["close"]
    volume = value["volume"]

    stock = stock_map.get(stock_name)
    if stock is not None:
        stock_info = {
            "stock": stock
            "date": date,
            "open_value": open_price,
            "close_value": close_price,
            "volume": volume
        }
        stocks.append(stock_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your current implementation could work.

```
s = Stock.objects.get(stock=stock_name, None)
stocks = []
if s:
   stock_info = {
        "stock": s
        "date": date,
        "open_value": open_price,
        "close_value": close_price,
        "volume": volume
    }
    stocks.append(stock_info)
```

For performance reasons it may be advantageous to do something more like this (exact syntax may not be correct:

```
stock_names = (_['code'] for _ in data)
s = Stock.objects.in_bulk(stock_name=stock_names)
stocks = []
for d in data:
  if d['code'] in s:
    stocks.append(...)
```

Comment: I guess - my only question then is, isn't it quite inefficient with a `get` inside a loop? Am I not performing a database operation on each iteration?

Comment: you want to check if something with a particular name exist in your DB, you'll have to make a call for that no matter what.

Comment: You'd probably be better off iterating through data to get a set of stock_names.  Then query for all records where stock_name is in that set.  My answer shows you how to do what you asked without that try/catch code.

Comment: Won't that code fail on `s = Stock.objects.get(stock=stock_name, None)` if the Stock doesn't exist? It'll throw a `DoesNotExist` exception.

And the None keyword is not valid. It says `Positional argument cannot appear after keyword arguments`

Comment: @erikvm try it and see.  If the stock doesn't exist what does it return?  Is the None necessary (I was assuming it worked like normal dict.get(), but maybe not).  Point is, there should be an easy way to tell from what that returns if that particular stock is in the database. Added 2nd example of what the code might look like to do it in 1 db query.